# Symfony2 Doctrine2 how to add object if not fetched from db

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, repository

Check this example: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#fetching-objects-from-the-database

What I got is:

```
$results = $applicationsRepo->findByInName($appInNames);
```

Where `appInNames` is an array looking like this:

```
array(
    app1_name => app1_name,
    app2_name => app2_name,
    app3_name => app3_name,
    ...
)
```

I want to create an entity object when it's not found. How to check if `app1_name` was returned and if not create one ?

Comment: What does your `findByInName` function look like?

Comment: it doesnt look like its the default structure `findBy` you can add the entity filed name in my case `inName` and search fetch by that field name `findByInName`

Comment: Is your code working when entities exist? I may be wrong, but for me `findByInName` should take the value of `inName`, not an array. What are you trying to achieve? You cannot query a _or_ criteria this way.

Comment: If you want to get all entities that match one of the names in your `$appInNames` array, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get an array of all entities that have `inName` attribute set to either of `app1_name`, `app2_name`, etc with a default value if it does not exists, you can use `findOneBy` instead of `findBy` and create your entity if the result is NULL.

May not be the most efficient method because of the loop but it give you what you need :

```
$results = array();
foreach($appInNames as $appInName) {
    $app = $applicationsRepo->findOneByInName($appInName);
    if(!isset($app)) {
        // Create you entity here
    }
    $results[$appInName] = $app;
}
```

A more efficient method may be to write a custom Repository and use the queryBuilder to add all your *OR* conditions. You'll get all the existing entities in one query, you will then have to parse the result to create the missing entities.